# Android Studio see device as null

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, xiaomi

On Ubuntu Android Studio shows devices as null.
Every time I turn on my laptop, I need to run the following console commands to add permissions:

```
./adb devices
./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb devices
```

Enter my password and then repeat:

```
./adb kill-server
./adb devices
```

Note I'm using a xiaomi phone.

Is there a way to get around this permission issues so I don't have to do it ever time.

Comment: Is a script which runs on startup no solution?

Comment: @dnsiv think that can help, but how to configure it?

Comment: Open .bashrc with vim or nano and write these lines in it. .bashrc will always be executed on startup

Comment: @dnsiv Added answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, what I did to solve this problem.

1. Defined in what cases I need to run these commands. For most ubuntu users there is a home folder (hidden file `.bashrc`).

   In which you can record the launch of these commands. But these commands will be triggered when you enter the `bash` command in the console.
2. Since I have a shell .zshrc then I did the following:

   open console: `gedit .zshrc`

When the file opens, add the following line:

```
./.add_device_permissions.sh
```

After or before, we need to create this file: `.add_device_permissions.sh` in which we write the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Add permissions for Xiaomi Redmi Note 5
ADB="/home/vadimm/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb"
$ADB devices
$ADB kill-server
cat .permissions_redmi_note | sudo -S $ADB devices
$ADB kill-server
cat .permissions_redmi_note | sudo -S $ADB devices
```

Also we need create .permissions_redmi_note where we need to hardcode our password.

3. Not to add to the file `.zshrc` unnecessary we can specify the path when starting the system itself: `Startup Applications Preferences`

Where we press on "Add" and write our command: `/home/vadimm/.add_device_permissions.sh`